# Failed to make bwa-0.6.1 on MacOS 10.11.6 El Capitan

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, gcc

I have failed to make bwa-0.6.1 on MacOS 10.11.6 El Capitan, I get the error below. I downloaded and installed Xcode8. I am running an application that requires an older version of bwa, precisely bwa.0.6.1

gcc -g -Wall -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD  QSufSort.o bwt_gen.o utils.o bwt.o bwtio.o bwtaln.o bwtgap.o is.o bntseq.o bwtmisc.o bwtindex.o ksw.o stdaln.o simple_dp.o bwaseqio.o bwase.o bwape.o kstring.o cs2nt.o bwtsw2_core.o bwtsw2_main.o bwtsw2_aux.o bwt_lite.o bwtsw2_chain.o bamlite.o fastmap.o bwtsw2_pair.o main.o -o bwa -lm -lz -lpthread
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_bwt_2occ", referenced from:
      _bwt_cal_width in bwtaln.o
  "_bwt_2occ4", referenced from:
      _bwt_match_gap in bwtgap.o
      _bsw2_core in bwtsw2_core.o
  "_bwtl_2occ4", referenced from:
      _bsw2_core in bwtsw2_core.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bwa] Error 1

Desperately need an answer.

Comment: Try `make clean && make`.

Comment: Returns the same error.